# Why redux-form wizard form can't save state?

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-form

I have a 2 step wizard form use redux-form, but when I return to the first page,the state of first page is disappeared, my form like below:

my container component:

```
...
import Add1 from './Add1';
import Add2 from './Add2';

class Add extends Component{
    render(){
        let { add } = this.props;
        return (
            <div>
                {add.get('step') == '1' && <Add1 {...this.props}/>}
                {add.get('step') == '2' && <Add2 {...this.props}/>}
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Add;
```

my Add1 component:

```
...
export const fields = ['username', 'password'];

class Add1 extends Component{
    toNextStep(){
        //change the step of state;
    }
    render(){
        let {fileds:{username, password}, handleSubmit} = this.props;

        return (
            <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(this.toNextStep.bind(this))}>
                <input type="text" {...username}/>
                <input type="text" {...password}/>
                <input type="submit" value="Next Step"/>
            </form>
        );
    }
}

export default reduxForm(
    {
        form: 'add',
        fields,
        destroyOnUnmount: false
    }
)(Add1);
```

my Add2 component:

```
...
export const fields = ['username', 'password', 'sex'];

class Add2 extends Component{
    toPrevPage(){
        //change the step of state;
    }
    render(){
        let {fields: {sex},handleSubmit} = this.props;
        return (
            <div>
               <select {...sex}>
                    <option value="1">Male</option>
                    <option value="2">Female</option>
               </select>
               <button type="button" onClick={this.toPrevPage.bind(this)}>Prev</button>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default reduxForm(
{
    form: 'add',
    fields: fields,
    destroyOnUnmount: false
},
state => {
    return {
        //If I have initalValues here, the problem is arisen!!!!
        initialValues: {
            sex: 2
        }
    }
}
)(Add2);
```

The problem is : when I have `initialValues` in second page, I click Prev button, the state of first page is disapeared(username and password) first time, I don't know how to deal this problem, can someone help me ?

Answer (score 1):

No need to have different form names. But this typo might be causing problems.

```
let {fileds:{username, password}, handleSubmit} = this.props;
     ^^^^^^
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to assign different names to your forms like `form: 'add1'` and `form: 'add2'` then you'll have a different piece of state for each so they would not be overridden